# How to compute integral $\int_0^\pi \ln\left(2\sin\frac x2\right)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to compute

$$\int_0^\pi \ln\left(2\sin\frac x2\right)dx$$

The primitive of the integrand does not seem to have a closed form. So I guess one would need to use symettry or trig identities in this case.

For some context, this is the first coefficient of a Fourier Series, but I would like to compute the integral using only real techniques, no complex analysis or so.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Mathematics Stack Exchange, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](//math.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts).

Answer (score 8):

\begin{align}
I= &\int_0^\pi \ln(2\sin\frac x2)dx\overset{x\to \pi -x}=\int_0^\pi \ln(2\cos\frac x2)dx\\
=& \ \frac12 \int_0^\pi \ln(2\sin\frac x2) +\ln(2\cos\frac x2)\ dx\\
= & \ \frac12 \int_0^\pi \ln(2\sin x)dx= \int_0
^{\pi/2} \ln(2\sin x)\overset{x\to \frac x2}{dx}\\
=& \ \frac12 \int_0^\pi \ln(2\sin\frac x2)dx=\frac12I=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here is just to show one mistake one can easily make (I did).

Do substitution twice

1. $x=2t$
   $$I_1=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}2\ln(2\sin t)dt$$
2. $t=\frac\pi2-u$
   $$I_2=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}2\ln(2\cos u)du$$
   then do averaging
   \begin{align}
   I&=\frac{I_1+I_2}{2}\\
   &=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\bigl(\ln(2\sin t)+\ln(2\cos t)\bigr)dt\\
   &\overset{\mathbf{wrong}}=\frac12\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\bigl(\ln(4\sin^2t)+\ln(4\cos^2t)\bigr)dt=\frac12\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln{4}dt=\frac\pi2\ln2\\
   &=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(2\sin 2t)dt\\
   &=\frac12\int_0^{\pi}\ln(2\sin x)dx\\
   &=\frac12I=0
   \end{align}